# Service did not give the controller data from a .json file?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to get `carData.json` file from a server using `AngularJS`.

Here is how I have structured it:

I have a `services.js` file (inside of `js` forlder) where I hold all of my `services` and `factories`. Here is the `factory` that I use to get `carData.json` file from a server:

```
carApp.factory('getAllCars', function($http){
    return {
        get: function() {
            return $http.get('data/carData.json');
        }
    };
});
```

I also have a `CarsByReviewCtrl` controller that uses the `carData.json` file for its purposes:

```
carApp.controller("CarsByReviewCtrl", function($scope, getAllCars) {
    getAllCars.get().success(function(data){
        $scope.allCars = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("AJAX failed")
    });
    $scope.carList = [];
    console.log($scope.allCars);
    ...
```

And finally here is the end of my `.html` file where I pass these `.js` files. (I have called the controller in the middle of my `html` file)

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/CarsByReviewCtrl.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, if I run my app and open the console, I would get the output of `undefined`, instead of javascript object that I got from the server.

**What have I done wrong and how can I fix that?**

Comment: Try putting this line `console.log($scope.allCars);` inside the `success` callback and check if it prints.

Comment: @bmleite: i am getting this error in the console: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/ng/areq?p0=CarsByRating&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: That seems to be a different problem. Can you please accept one of the answers to this question and then post a new question with the new problem? Try to indicate where the property `CarsByRating` is being used and how it is being defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print the content of `$scope.allCars` before the HTTP request is resolved.

Added some comments to your code in order to explain how you should be reading it:

```
carApp.controller("CarsByReviewCtrl", function($scope, getAllCars) {
    // first line of JS to be invoked
    getAllCars.get().success(function(data){
       // this will be executed later in time, after receiving the HTTP response (case success)
       $scope.allCars = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // this will be executed later in time, after receiving the HTTP response (case error)
       alert("AJAX failed")
    });

    // this will be executed immediately after the previous JS line: getAllCars.get()
    $scope.carList = [];

    // this will be executed immediately after the previous JS line
    console.log($scope.allCars);
```

Comment: i am getting this error in the console: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/ng/areq?p0=CarsByRating&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Answer (score 1):

the problem is: `console.log($scope.allCars)` runs before the success handler runs. 
you can change your code to:

```
carApp.controller("CarsByReviewCtrl", function($scope, getAllCars) {
    getAllCars.get().success(function(data){
        $scope.allCars = data;
        console.log($scope.allCars);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("AJAX failed")
    });
    $scope.carList = [];

    ...
```

Comment: i am getting this error in the console: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/ng/areq?p0=CarsByRating&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined